# use image urls from PG db to for multiple background-images in css/rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to change the *background-image* property of a div to equal the url from my PG db in my rails app.

**HTML.ERB**

```
<div class="blogBody hCenterBlock">
  <% @item.each do |i| %>
    <div class="newsItem">
      <div class="section group blogTitle">
        <div class="col col12">
          <h2 class="newsTitle">
            <%= i.title %>
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section group blogItem">
        <%= link_to(i.url,:class => "fancybox fancybox.iframe", 'data-thumbnail' => "#{i.image.thumb.url}", :rel => "gallery", :title => "#{i.title}") do %>
          <div class="col7 col blogImage">
            <div class="newsImg"></div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <div class="col5 col blogDescript">
          <p><%= i.description %></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

**CSS**

This is not all the CSS, but it is what I am trying to accomplish. I want the background image of the div to be filled with whatever is in the database for each item separately. Is this possible to do? Do I need an asset helper?

```
.newsImg {
    background-image: url("#{i.image.url}"
}
```

All help is much appreciated! Thanks Again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you won't be able to populate your [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#main-features) CSS (static) from your db; you'll need to use inline styling (in the views/layout):

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<body style="<%= @bg_image %>">
 ...
</body>
```

To populate this, the simplest way is to use a [`before_action` filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) in your `ApplicationController` to get the image value from the db:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_bg

   private

   def set_bg
      @bg_image = ....
   end
end
```

The obvious problem with this is that it initiates a db call each time you send a request. The best way around this is to either have a conditional call, or use [caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) to store the value.

Comment: so if i had a list of 20 different items and each had their own different image, how would rails know which **@bg_image** goes with the correct **@item**?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me but I will have to use caching.

```
<div class="blogBody hCenterBlock">
  <% @item.each do |i| %>
    <% @bg_image = i.image.url %>
    <div class="newsItem">
      <div class="section group blogTitle">
        <div class="col col12">
          <h2 class="newsTitle">
            <%= i.title %>
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section group blogItem">
        <%= link_to(i.url,:class => "fancybox fancybox.iframe", 'data-thumbnail' => "#{i.image.thumb.url}", :rel => "gallery", :title => "#{i.title}") do %>
          <div class="col7 col blogImage" style="background: url(<%= i.image.url %>)"></div>
        <% end %>
        <div class="col5 col blogDescript">
          <p>
            <%= i.description %>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I changed the inline styling to this:

```
<div class="col7 col blogImage" style="background: url(<%= i.image.url %>)"></div>
```

Thanks for all the help!